# Invalid data table format: must have at least 2 columns

Tags: javascript, c#, arrays, json, asp.net-mvc

I have a JSON string something like:

```
[
   {
      "Year":2018,
      "Ov":1000,
      "PD":2000,
      "OL":3000
   },
   {
      "Year":2017,
      "Ov":4000,
      "PD":5000,
      "OL":6000
   },
   {
      "Year":2012,
      "Ov":600,
      "PD":400,
      "OL":200
   },
   {
      "Year":2013,
      "Ov":700,
      "PD":500,
      "OL":200
   },
   {
      "Year":2014,
      "Ov":700,
      "PD":400,
      "OL":300
   },
   {
      "Year":2015,
      "Ov":700,
      "PD":300,
      "OL":400
   },
   {
      "Year":2016,
      "Ov":500,
      "PD":300,
      "OL":200
   },
   {
      "Year":2017,
      "Ov":4000,
      "PD":5000,
      "OL":6000
   },
   {
      "Year":2018,
      "Ov":1000,
      "PD":2000,
      "OL":3000
   }
]
```

My Html Code:

```
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['bar']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      var array = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Proj.Dash.JsonString));
     alert("JSON.stringify " + array);

     var dataArr = array.data;

    function drawChart() {
        var dataArray = [['Year', 'Ov', 'PD', 'OL']];

        for (var i in dataArr) {
            dataArray.push([dataArr[i].Year,dataArr[i].Ov,dataArr[i].PD,dataArr[i].OL]);
        }
        alert(dataArray.length);

          var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([dataArray


        ]);

        var options = {
            chart: {
                title: '',
                subtitle: '',
            },
            bars: 'vertical',
            vAxis: { format: 'decimal' },
            height: 500,
            colors: ['#333333', '#3490e9', '#ff5a00'],
            legend: {
                position: 'none'
            }




        };

        var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('columnchart_material'));
        chart.draw(data, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options));
      }
```

When I run the code it returns a null with this error:

> Invalid data table format: must have at least 2 columns.

What do I missed up?

Any suggestion is much appreciated.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `i.Year` ,`i.OV` etc?

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems coming from this line:

```
var dataArr = array.data;
```

You're trying to access `data` property which is not found inside the JSON string, hence `dataArr` returns `undefined` and causing `dataArray.length` returns 1, which throwing exception as mentioned in question because only column headers exist inside the array passed into `arrayToDataTable()` function.

To pass the data properly, you need to use `JSON.parse()` so that the JSON string returned as array:

```
var dataArr = JSON.parse(array);
```

This will produce array with which contains column headers and values like this example:

```
[["Year", "Ov", "PD", "OL"],    
[2018, 1000, 2000, 3000],
[2017, 4000, 5000, 6000],
[2012, 600, 400, 200],
[2013, 700, 500, 200],
[2014, 700, 400, 300],
[2015, 700, 300, 400],
[2016, 500, 300, 200],
[2017, 4000, 5000, 6000],
[2018, 1000, 2000, 3000]]
```

**Update:**

The second problem is you're defining `[dataArray]` which actually creates nested array, this causing `wg` property in `data` has zero length array and the chart not properly displayed, hence you should remove outer array square brackets:

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(dataArray);
```

And the third problem is that you're duplicating data groups (i.e. `[2017, 4000, 5000, 6000]` in 2 different series). You should remove duplicated part using custom function.

Therefore, your code should be look like example below:

```
var array = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Proj.Dash.JsonString));
alert("JSON.stringify " + array);

var dataArr = JSON.parse(array);

function drawChart() {
    var dataArray = [['Year', 'Ov', 'PD', 'OL']];

    for (var i in dataArr) {
        dataArray.push([dataArr[i].Year, dataArr[i].Ov, dataArr[i].PD, dataArr[i].OL]);
    }

    alert(dataArray.length);

    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(dataArray);

    var options = {
        chart: {
            title: '',
            subtitle: '',
        },
        bars: 'vertical',
        hAxis: { format: '#' }, // optional
        vAxis: { format: 'decimal' },
        height: 500,
        colors: ['#333333', '#3490e9', '#ff5a00'],
        legend: {
            position: 'none'
        }
    };

    var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('columnchart_material'));
    chart.draw(data, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options));
}
```

Additional reference: [arrayToDataTable() function](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#google.visualization.arraytodatatable)

Working example: [.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/qK5gsl)

Comment: thanks @Tetsuya arrayToDataTable si my problem now..  when i get the content `dataArray` of dataArray manually it's woking bat when i run the code with a variable of `dataArray` has no luck.. the chart is empty.. do you have any idea. why it is happening?

Comment: I edited the answer and added a fiddle to show how the chart should work. The problem is duplicated `2017` & `2018` data inside the series, then passing `dataArray` directly instead of using nested array.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using your script in same html file or there is a separate script file. Please clarify. If its a separate file try loading your script in same html.

Comment: I am not using a file i am using this `@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Proj.Dash.JsonString));`

Comment: Declare your array in first line and use the google.chart.load in beneath of first. Hope this should work.

Comment: Thanks @ Amardeep Kumar Agrawal can you show your idea here